# LazyInitializationException error

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

I have class `TestPrint`:

```
@Entity
public class TestPrint implements Serializable{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "testPrint", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Commants> testPrintCommants = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and `Commants` class

```
@Entity
public class Commants implements Serializable{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "testPrint_id", nullable = false)
    private TestPrint testPrint;
}
```

I want to show list `testPrintCommants` in my `TestPrint.xhtml` page .

Comment: you should show your query. You could use fetch = FetchType.EAGER byt it could have a cost in terms of loading. The idea would be to load testPrintCommants fields only in this query.

Comment: I think you should use FetchType.EAGER. 
How do you access entities? Session beans?

Comment: Add also fetch = FetchType.LAZY to your ManyToOne relationship

Comment: Can you add your error log ?

Comment: lazyinitializationexception could not initialize proxy - no session